# Python3:writing to a file ,I don't know which encoding to use?

Tags: python-3.x, file-writing

I want to write every character to a file:

```
aa=0
i=100/2750
import sys
with open('chr.txt','w',encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for a,b,c,d in zip(range(0,27500),range(27500,55000),range(55000,82500),range(82500,110000)):
        f.write(chr(a))
        f.write(chr(b))
        f.write(chr(c))
        f.write(chr(d))
        aa+=1
        sys.stdout.write('\r'+str(round(i*aa,2))+'%')
    f.write(str(chr(110000)))
```

The problem is that using the above code only some characters are getting written.

So what should be the encoding?

Comment: Is there any pattern about which characters are written and which are not?

Comment: @NicoHaase pattern doesn't matter , I was hoping to speed up the process.. I guess